# Combining multiple observations n R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this table with multiple observations

[image: 1]

I want the table to look like this

[image: 2]

The observations MI and MA have multiple values which I want to add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the dplyr approach:

```
library("dplyr")

dataset %>%
  group_by(st_name) %>%
  summarize(all_bills = sum(all_bills))
```

Also, here's the dataset:

```
dataset <- structure(list(
  all_bills = c(33, 57, 126, 23, 97, 58, 27),
  st_name   = c("AL", "MI", "MI", "MA", "SC", "VA", "MA")),
  .Names = c("all_bills", "st_name"),
  row.names = c(NA,-7L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Ritz735, the answer is also useful

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` to do a group by `sum`

```
aggregate(all_bills ~ st_name, df1, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. The answer is quite helpful